# Самовольное изменение статуса заказа

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Заказчики сайта жалуются на то, что в WooCommerce некоторые заказы непонятным образом изменили свои статусы на "На удержании" с других статусов. В том числе из статуса "Выполнен".
Админка обычно отображает менеджера, который произвёл изменение статуса. В данном случае ответственное лицо не указывается. Как будто программа сама произвела изменения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Кто-то с таким сталкивался когда-нибудь?
И как можно отследить такие изменения, кроме как в админке?

UPD Не сказал, что я вносил некоторые изменения в functions.php дочерней темы. Ставил по умолчанию при оформлении заказа статус "На удержании" :

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'on_hold_order'); 
function on_hold_order($order_id) { 
    if (! $order_id) { 
     return; 
    } 
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id); 
    $order->update_status('on-hold');
}
```

Не представляю, как это может повлиять на суть заданного вопроса, но я ещё слабо знаю WordPresss.

Comment: Исходя из той инфы что вы дали, либо пользователь повторно заходит на страницу выполненного заказа, либо вы где-то еще триггерите шаблон thankyou.php т.к. там вызывается этот хук

Comment: @Алексей А разве возможно покупателю повторно заходить в свой заказ и производить какие-либо действия с ним? Кроме как просмотреть?

Comment: Судя по вашему коду, когда пользователь открывает страницу thank-you статус становится on-hold. Просто кривой кусок кода)

Comment: @Алексей Точно! Я как-то не подумал, что пользователь может повторно открыть эту страницу. Спасибо.
А как тогда правильно реализовать автоматическое изменение статуса при совершении заказа? Какой хук использовать?

Comment: Можете поправить свой вариант вот тут [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985488/set-woocommerce-order-status-when-order-is-created-from-processing-to-pending)

Comment: @Алексей Спасибо за ссылку. Но я, оказывается, делал всё, как советует автор ответа на вопрос по ссылке. Я даже if( ! $order_id ) return; ставил. Т.е. дело, похоже, не в этом куске кода.

Comment: в том ответе идет проверка на статус, и только если статус `processing` меняется на нужный, в вашем коде я этого не вижу.

Comment: @Алексей Но при посещении страницы "woocommerce_thankyou", как я понимаю, $order_id не передаётся и дальнейший код не должен выполняться. Или я ошибаюсь?